# Is it even possible to initialize data like this? JavaFX ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx

I'm following the MVP pattern so the Presenter has access to the view and to the model and the view to the presenter. 
View <-> Presenter -> Model.

My problem is, I can't populate the ComboBox. I am an amateur and this one here breaks me. I think I have a fundamental issue.

The Main class:

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{

private Presenter presenter;
private Model model;
private ViewController view;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    presenter = initData();
    testSampleData();

    model.showList(); // prints out: [Susi 22, Peter 30, Tom 54]

    AnchorPane paneMain = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(paneMain);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public void testSampleData()
{
    model.getList().add(new Person("Susi", 22));
    model.getList().add(new Person("Peter", 30));
    model.getList().add(new Person("Tom", 54));
}

private Presenter initData()
{
    presenter = new Presenter();
    model = new Model();
    view = new ViewController();

    presenter.setModel(model);
    presenter.setView(view);
    view.setPresenter(presenter);

    return presenter;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Im trying to create an ComboBox with Objects. 
The Person Class:

```
package test;
public class Person 
{
private String name;
private int age;

public Person(String name, int alter)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = alter;
}

public String toString()
{
    return name + " " +  age;
}
}
```

The data is stored in the model class:

```
package test;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Model
{
private ObservableList<Person> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void showList()
{
    System.out.println(this.list.toString());
}

public ObservableList<Person> getList()
{
    return list;
}

public void initTest()
{
    list.add(new Person("Susi", 22));
    list.add(new Person("Peter", 30));
    list.add(new Person("Tom", 54));
}

}
```

The presenter is the "bridge" between view and model

```
package test;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Presenter
{
private Model myModel;
private ViewController myViewController;

public void setModel(Model model)
{
    this.myModel = model;
}

public void setView(ViewController view)
{
    this.myViewController = view;
}

public ObservableList<Person> getList()
{
    return myModel.getList();
}

}
```

And here is the view:

```
package test;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class ViewController 
{
Presenter presenter;

@FXML
private Label myLabel;

@FXML
private ComboBox<Person> myComboBox;

@FXML       
private TextArea myTextArea;

private ObservableList<Person> list;

@FXML
private void handleComboBoxAction() {
  Person selectedPerson = myComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
  myTextArea.appendText("Selected Person: " + selectedPerson + "\n");
}

public ViewController()
{
//        myComboBox.setItems(presenter.getList());  // -> nullpointer
}

public void initialize()
{
    list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

//        list = presenter.getList(); // -> this is my goal 

    list.add(new Person("Tom", 54));  // this here works, but I want to get the data from the model class :(
//        myComboBox.setItems(list);

}

public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter)
{
    this.presenter = presenter;
}
}
```

Last but not least, the fxml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.geometry.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

    <AnchorPane minHeight="300.0" minWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="test.ViewController">
       <children>
          <BorderPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
             <center>
                <ComboBox fx:id="myComboBox" onAction="#handleComboBoxAction" prefWidth="150.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
             </center>
             <right>
                <TextArea fx:id="myTextArea" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
             </right>
          </BorderPane>
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Perhaps I spammed to much code in here but I thought it would be necessary.

EDIT:

I edited the FXML part in my main like this:

```
    loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));
    AnchorPane paneMain = (AnchorPane)loader.load();
    view = (ViewController)loader.getController();
```

And now the advice from NAMS and James_D works!

Comment: Why not just initialize the combo box elements in the `setPresenter` method?

Comment: James has it right. You get `NullPointerException` in the controller constructor because you haven't initialized the presenter when the constructor runs. Moving that code into `setPresenter` should solve it.

Comment: I altered the code like this:
        this.presenter = presenter;
        myComboBox.setItems(presenter.getList());
in the setPresenter method from the controller but it still gives me null-pointer.

Comment: I experimented a lot and now I can populate the list with my data sample via the setPresenter method. The thing is, when the FXML gets loaded, the list with all the People disappears and so the ComboBox can't be filled.  @NAMS

Comment: @beefproggs When you load the list of people, have you called `initTest()` or otherwise put any data into it before you call `getList()`? If there's no data in the list then there would be nothing to show in the combo box, and looking at your code, I don't see any calls to `initTest()` anywhere, so you're probably using an empty list.